# Transfer Select option value into ul li

Tags: javascript, php

I have select option that I want to use it as ul li but it's not working when I use ul li.

Here is my code:

```
<select class="order" onchange ="sortex();">
<option <?php  if($order==1){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="1">Up to Low</option>
<option <?php  if($order==2){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="2">Low to High</option>
<option <?php  if($order==3){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="3">A to Z </option>
<option <?php  if($order==4){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="4">Z to A </option>
</select>
```

and here is my function:

```
function sortex(){
myurl='<?php echo $link;  ?>';
val=$(".order").val();
order='?order='+val;
finalurl= myurl+order;
window.location.replace(finalurl);
}
```

I want to use it in **ul li class** but when I use ul li then it's not working !

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-wide">
<li <?php  if($order==1){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="1">Up to Low </li>
<li <?php  if($order==2){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="2">Low to High </li>
<li <?php  if($order==3){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="3">A to Z </li>
<li <?php  if($order==4){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> value="4">Z to A </li>
</ul>
```

> How to use it in ul li? the problem is when I use ul li then data information won't be sorted, but when I use select option then it works well and data will be sorted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: `<li>`-elements doesn't have any property called `selected` or `value`. They are _not_ interchangeable with each other.

Comment: You probably want an actual class named `selected`, not the property `selected`. I don't think you can apply that attribute to an `li`

Comment: You're not closing the `<li>` elements.

Comment: you can close `</li>` and use class like `class='selecte'`

Comment: When I use select option, it's working well, but when I use ul li, then it's not working . what's the wrong ?

Comment: please explain what  is the problem that you are facing here.

Comment: Li is closed, and I added class "order" and "selected" into ul class, but not working ! and I also added onchange ="sortex();" into ul too

Comment: Repeating _"not working"_ doesn't clarify anything at all!. Please read all comments. li and select are _NOT_ interchangeable. To be able to use li instead of select, you need to build all functionality and  style (css) yourself.

Comment: I mean ((not working)) means the table information based on SORT not working. data won't be sorted A to Z or Z to A, and etc,

Comment: You're using Bootstrap right? That dropdown is supposed to be used with links (`<a>`) only. It's not supposed to replace a `select` tag.

Comment: Again. `value` is NOT a valid attribute for a `li` element. You can NOT just change a `select` into a `<ul><li>` and expect it to work the same. I'm not sure how many times this needs to be said?

Answer (score 0):

What it seems you're trying to do is to use [Bootstrap's Dropdowns](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/) as a replacement for a `select` tag. Maybe you want a better-looking select than the default, style-less select element.

Sadly, Bootstrap's Dropdowns **aren't supposed to work as a select element**; it only groups a bunch of links. However, it's possible to do what you want if you use `onclick` on every element to call the sorting function:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Sort
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="sortex(1);">Up to low</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="sortex(2);">Low to high</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You would have to change the function:

```
function sortex(sortBy){
  var myurl='<?php echo $link;  ?>';
  var order='?order='+sortBy;
  var finalurl= myurl+order;
  window.location.replace(finalurl);
}
```

**I wouldn't recommend this** though because this doesn't support a "selected" value, because (again), this Dropdown isn't supposed to be used like this!

So just stick to the default select tag, or if you really want a nicer Select tag, search for a library that creates stylized select elements.